# Deployment gaps at fast pace growing application

Tags: kubernetes, process, openshift, development-environment, cicd

Some context:

I have little experience with ci/CD and manage a fast paced growing application since it saw the light of the day for the first time. It is composed by several microservices at different environments. Devs are constantly pushing new code to DEV , but they frequently forget about sending new values from their local .`env` ove to the openshift cloud, regardless of this being a brand new environment or existing ones.

The outcome? Services that fail because they lack to have their secrets updated.

I understand the underlying issue is lack of communication between both us DevOps staff and devs themselves. But I've been trying to figure out some sort of process that would make sure we are not missing anything. Maybe something like a "before takeoff checklist" (yes, like the ones pilots do in a real flight preparation): if the chack fails then the aircraft is not ready to takeoff.

So the question is for everyone out there that practices DevOps. How do you guys deal with this?

Does anyone automates this within Openshift/kubernetes, for example? From your perspective and experience, would you suggest any tools for that, or simply enforce communication?

Answer (score 2):

Guess no checklist or communication would work for team that `...frequently forget about sending new values from their local .env ove...`, which you must have already done.

Your step in the pipeline should check for service availability before proceeding to next step, eg. does the service has endpoint registered within acceptable time, no endpoint means the backing pod(s) did not enter readiness state as expected. In such case, rollback and send notification to the team responsible for the service/application and exit cleanly.

There's no fix formula for CI/CD, especially human error. Check & balance at every step is the least you can do to trigger early warning and avoid a disastrous deployment.